# What do you mean by quark gluon plasma is frictionless?

Tags: friction, bose-einstein-condensate, superfluidity, quark-gluon-plasma

I read about the similarities between quark gluon plasma and Bose Einstein condensate especially both are frictionless, I know generally when everday object rubs against one another the electrons get excited and emits radiation but what about this extreme state of matter? Does it flow into one another without loss of kinetic energy like in BEC?